# "refresh" values

Tags: excel, vba

Why AutoFilter function doesn't work. I have made easy code in VBA that will filter table to doesn't show row with date that is before today. Code looks like below:

```
Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & Date
```

Column C looks like: 22.01.2020 etc.

The code works because it was filter some dates that year was 2019 but it didn't do the work with previous date but in 2020. Why?

EDIT:

I find out something. I just replace values in that column via VBA before and values are simply date but they are on a left sight. If I just click on the value, does nothing and click enter it's kinda refresh and works fine. How to refresh cells like this in VBA?

Comment: 22.01.2020  doesnt look like date, its a string value.

Comment: @vDs1 It is a valid date in locales where the date separator is `.`.

Comment: `How to refresh cells like this in VBA?` - https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your dates are represented as string.

Please select column C where your dates are included and perform the following

Data > Text to Column > Finish

VBA Equivalent:

```
Range("C:C").TextToColumns
Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & Date
```